# Autowiring of generic types doesn't work [Spring 4+]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, generics, autowired

I'm working on one project with Spring 4.2.4.RELEASE.

I've heard about new features Spring 4 (especially about [autowiring of generic types](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics)), and I was confused when the following code hadn't been compiled:

```
@Service
public interface AuthenticationService<T> { ... }

public class VKAuthenticationService implements AuthenticationService<VKToken> { ... }

@RestController
public class VKAuthenticationController {
   @Autowired
   private AuthenticationService<VKToken> service;
}
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Not sure.. but did you try adding @Service on class VKAuthenticationService?

Comment: @AnkitBansal, I hadn't tried before, but now it's working fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about also declare `@Service` on your `VKAuthenticationService`

```
@Service(name="myService")
public class VKAuthenticationService implements AuthenticationService<VKToken> { ... }
```

and use `@Autowired` and `@Qualifier` to inject it

```
@RestController
public class VKAuthenticationController {
   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("myService")
   private AuthenticationService<VKToken> service;
}
```

Comment: does `@Service` pass from parent to child?

Comment: when declare @Service at interface, it's no use since an interface can not be made into instance.

Comment: so like you said, you should declare @Service at concrete class, and give it a name. The default name will be the class name, in your case, it should be vKAuthenticationService.

Comment: And since you declare the field service as an interface type, if you have many instances in your spring which all implement the interface AuthenticationService<VKToken>. Spring will not know which one should be autowired to the field. So it's better use @Qualifier to specify it.